# matching multi-word strings via if statement in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I got a bit of question here.
The input is this line:

```
configure vlan test bla bla
```

and its stored in variable *line* as a list (via split()).

If I evaluate it based on my first if statement below it fails

```
 if ("configure" in line) and (" vlan" in line):
    print("create vlans");
```

If I evaluate it based on the next if statement below it succeeds.

```
if ("configure vlan" in line):
    print("create vlans 2");
```

Why is that? I just simply put the two string together but one works and the other doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the output of `print(line)`?

Comment: Both work for me...

Comment: Try testing for `'configure'` and `' vlan'` separately to see which is failing.

Comment: Any chance you actually have a list containing `"configure vlan"`?

Comment: I do. line is set via the split function which gives it as a list. I will update the post

Comment: is this why it doesn't work? That I am evaluating a string against a list?

Comment: Because although `"configure vlan"` **is** in the list, the substrings are not. You would need to check if `any` of the strings in the list contain both `"configure"` and `" vlan"`.

Comment: if you used `split` to create the list of words then `" vlan"` would not be in the list. `"vlan"` would. (no space)

Comment: ah that's why. thx guys